# For loop keeps crashing program c++

Tags: c++

This specific chunk of code from my much longer program keeps crashing. It compiles fine but then windows ends it.

```
 out_stream_names.open("names.dat");
 for(int i = a.size(); i>0 ; i=i-1)
       {
             out_stream_names << a[i] << endl;
       }
 out_stream_names.close();
```

I would like to figure out why it keeps crashing. I'm not asking for code to copy. Thanks.

Comment: `a[a.size()]` is most likely out of bounds, unless there's some weird overloading going on, as could be the case in a `std::map`.

Answer (score 5):

Very little info. But the first thing that strikes is the `a.size()`

Try:

```
 out_stream_names.open("names.dat");
 for(int i = a.size()-1; i>=0 ; i=i-1)
       {
             out_stream_names << a[i] << endl;
       }
 out_stream_names.close();
```

---

Since you want output in even indexes only, which in case of our traversal are the odd indexes, Use:

```
if(i&1) out_stream_names << a[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Off by 1 at `i>0` should also include `0` (missing `a[0]`)

Comment: seems like he does, he went from `a.size()` to `>0` (which means he wanted all the characters) so I think the OP wants `0th` element too

Comment: @Aniket That's correct, I want 0th element up until the a.size() element.

Comment: ah @user22507 I guessed so

Comment: @loxxy The goal of this code is to reverse out_stream the even number indexes of the input file. So if i=0 to i=5 is 1a2b3c then I want this code to output 1 and 2 and 3 and then reverse them to 3 2 1.

Comment: @user22507 Just check if i is at the even index before printing.

Comment: @loxxy can it be that a.size() counts starting at 1 instead of 0? It's saying that my in.dat is 8 in size but thats going from line 1 to line 8.

Comment: Any array starts with index of 0. Line 1 is for your ease, otherwise everything internally starts with 0.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise avoiding this sort of problem by using something on the order of:

```
std::copy(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<a::value_type>(out_stream_names, "\n"));
```

As a bonus, in this case you'll probably get a bit of a performance boost as well (from replacing `endl` with `\n`, avoiding flushing the stream between each name you write).

[Note that `a::value_type` won't compile as-is -- you need to specify the actual type].

Comment: Thanks Jerry Coffin! However, I am limited in the syntax I can use.

Answer (score 1):

```
out_stream_names.open("names.dat");
for(int i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
{
   out_stream_names << a[i] << endl;
}
out_stream_names.close();
```

?? try that!

Comment: What's the difference there Aniket?